# Help with TF31003 error

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I can enter via web http://localhost:8080/tfs/web with any user, from remote or local, but when I try to enter via Teamprise or VSTS2010 I get that error that my credentials are correct but I dont have the persmissions, why? I have tryed with Admin account and user Account too...

> TF31003: Your user account does not
>   have permission to connect to the team
>   foundation server at
>   http://x.x.x.x:8080/tfs/cibercell_dc
>   ask your server administrator to add
>   the appropiate permission to your
>   account

I review the event viewer and I get the follow NT Event :

```
TF53010: The following error has occurred in a Team Foundation component or extension:
Date (UTC): 14/01/2010 07:49:36 p.m.
Machine: WS08R2
Application Domain: /LM/W3SVC/8081/ROOT-1-129079721685126418
Assembly: Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a; v2.0.50727
Service Host: 
Process Details:
  Process Name: w3wp
  Process Id: 8148
  Thread Id: 7972
  Account name: CIBERCELL\Administrator

Detailed Message: TF53008: The authentication type  is not supported.

Web Request Details
    Url: http://190.43.252.222:8081/TeamFoundation/Administration/v3.0/LocationService.asmx [method: POST]
    User Agent: Team Foundation (devenv.exe, 10.0.21006.1)
    Headers: Cache-Control=max-age%3d259200&Connection=keep-alive&Via=1.1+bsd.resonanciamedica.com%3a3128+(squid%2f2.6.STABLE16)%2c+1.0+bsd.resonanciamedica.com%3a3128+(squid%2f2.5.STABLE14)&Content-Length=370&Content-Type=application%2fsoap%2bxml%3b+charset%3dutf-8&Accept-Encoding=gzip&Accept-Language=es-PE&Host=190.43.252.222%3a8081&User-Agent=Team+Foundation+(devenv.exe%2c+10.0.21006.1)&X-TFS-Version=1.0.0.0&X-TFS-Session=4a978cb7-31fa-4632-b8f9-bda681100a90&TF-Instance=4a978cb7-31fa-4632-b8f9-bda681100a90&SOAPAction=http%3a%2f%2fmicrosoft.com%2fwebservices%2fConnect&X-Forwarded-For=192.168.0.43%2c+192.168.0.200
    Path: /TeamFoundation/Administration/v3.0/LocationService.asmx
    Local Request: False
    Host Address: 209.45.92.194
    User: NT AUTHORITY\IUSR [authentication type: ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When installing TFS 2010 Beta 2, did you add NTLM authentication support in the IIS options?

TFS by default uses NTLM (Windows Integrated authentication) to authenticate with the server.  The fact that you can access the server as any user suggests that the IIS web application that is the Team Foundation Server application tier does not have authentication enabled for some reason.

Comment: I used NTLM Authentication on the install, but how can I reconfigure it? I choose a system acount : NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL NETWORK, it seems that IIS cant reconigzed the authentication